# How to split an unicode string to multiple characters?

Tags: javascript, string, unicode, split

My example:

```js
let $log = console.log;

for (let i of 'Nguyễn Thanh Tú') $log(i);
```

Output:

```
N 
g 
u 
y 
ê 
̃ 
n 
T 
h 
a 
n 
h 
T 
u 
́
```

I want (my goal) to split the string to:

```
N
g
u
y
ễ
n

T
h
a
n
h

T
ú
```

But I've 2 problems inside the code.

1. It splits `[ễ]` to `[ê, ~]`. I want `[ễ]` instead.
2. It splits `[ T]` to `[ T]`. I want `[ ,T]` instead.

I've also tried:

```js
let arr = 'Nguyễn Thanh Tú'.split('');

arr.forEach(x => $log(x));
```

It logs same result to the first case.

How can I solve these problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latest browsers, you can use [`String#normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize):

```js
for (let c of 'Nguyễn Thanh Tú'.normalize()) console.log(c)
```

Comment: The only reason I think it works is because I ran it on my browser and it did. Does yours give different results? That would be interesting.

Comment: I didn't look closely enough, it *does* need to be normalized.

Comment: But note that you don't need to spread it into an array. Just normalizing is sufficient. The OP's `let ... of` works on the normalized string the way they said they wanted.

Comment: Good point. I saw the many lines of output and assumed the OP wanted an array of characters when in fact a stream would have been just fine.